# Scala converting List of case class to List of another case class

Tags: scala, case-class

```
case class student1(name :String, marks :Long)
 
case class student2(studentName:String, marks:Long)
 
val mylist:List[student1] = List( student1("a",100) , student1("b",200))
```

How can I convert `mylist` into `List[student2]` in more elegant way than this?

```
val res: List[student2] = mylist.map(s => student2(s.name,s.marks))
```

Comment: What is wrong or _"unelegant"_ (whatever that means) from your solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add an auxiliary constructor.

```
case class student2(studentName:String, marks:Long) {
  def this(s:student1) = this(s.name, s.marks)
}

. . .

val res: List[student2] = mylist.map(new student2(_))
```

Or you could just do a pattern match, but for that you really should capitalize your class names.

```
val res: List[Student2] =
  mylist.map{case Student1(n,m) => Student2(n,m)}
```

Answer (score 2):

[**@sarveshseri**'s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69493455/5249621) ([**@esse**'s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69503357/5249621)) solution seems to be the simplest one in Scala 2 (Scala 3). The following solutions using libraries are harder but more flexible.

---

If you have the only such transormation I'd stay with your approach or with the one suggested by **@wvh**.

If you have many such transformations consider to use one of data manipulating libraries.

For example [Chimney](https://github.com/scalalandio/chimney)

```
import io.scalaland.chimney.dsl._

val res: List[student2] = mylist.map(
  _.into[student2]
   .withFieldRenamed(_.name, _.studentName)
   .transform
)
```

or [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless)

```
import shapeless.{Generic, HList}

trait Convert[A, B] {
  def apply(a: A): B
}
object Convert {
  implicit def mkConvert[A <: Product, B <: Product, L <: HList](implicit
    genericA: Generic.Aux[A, L],
    genericB: Generic.Aux[B, L]
  ): Convert[A, B] = a => genericB.from(genericA.to(a))
}

implicit class ConvertOps[A](val a: A) extends AnyVal {
  def to[B](implicit convert: Convert[A, B]): B = convert(a)
}

val res: List[student2] = mylist.map(_.to[student2])
```

Also look at [Monocle](https://github.com/optics-dev/Monocle) or [Quicklens](https://github.com/softwaremill/quicklens).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, please name your `classes` in `CapitalCamelCase`. So `Student1` and `Student2`.

Now, If you have two exactly same `case classes` like in this case, you can easily convert between them without using any libraries.

```
val myList2: List[Student2] = 
  mylist.map(s => Student2.tupled(Student1.unapply(s).get))
```

This will work for any two `case classes` `A` and `B` which are similar in strcuture.

Comment: Nice. Upvoting.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Scala 3 (aka dotty), the following code works:

```
scala> import scala.deriving.Mirror
                                                                                                                                                                           
scala> mylist.map(summon[Mirror.Of[student2]].fromProduct)
val res1: List[student2] = List(student2(a,100), student2(b,200))
```